# Why is printing to OneNote not as high quality in 2010 as the 2007 version?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, printing

I have recently updated Microsoft Office to the 2010 version so that my "Print to OneNote" option will work with Windows 7. It seems that with the new 2010 version of OneNote, printouts are not as clear as the 2007 version. Is there some way I can increase the quality of printouts (especially from Powerpoint) with OneNote 2010? I have tried checking the option "high quality" in powerpoint while printing, but its still not good enough to read small text.

Answer (score 2):

For me (using Windows XP) this problem seems to occur when using the print feature "Send to Onenote 2010" for printing to a notebook that still uses he Onenote 2007 format. When printing to a new notebook (that is, using the Onenote 2010 format) everything is crystal clear.

(However, when trying to copy the printout to the 2007 notebook, the quality is also reduced. Which means I will probably have to convert my workbooks to the new format...)